# How can I get draft.js to recognize the escape key?

Tags: javascript, key-bindings, draftjs

I would like to cancel input and clear the field in my app when the user types the escape key.  We tried testing for e.which === 27 in the keyBindingFn, but that function is never even invoked when the escape key is pressed (it is invoked just fine for normal keys, modifier keys, and arrow keys).  How can I detect an Escape keypress in draft.js?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Editor component has onEscape property

```js
<Editor 
    editorState={this.state.editorState} 
    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} 
    onEscape={keyEvent=>console.log('Escape just  pressed')}
    ref="editor"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

We solved this with an onKeyDown handler in the editor's enclosing div.  I'm not thrilled with the solution and hope someone has a better one, but this at least works.